# GnuPG home directory

Tags: gnupg, home-directory

The following is the code that I have been trying.

```
import os
import gnupg
import pdb
pdb.set_trace()
gpg = gnupg.GPG(gnupghome='new')
input_data = gpg.gen_key_input(
    key_type="RSA",key_length=1024,
    passphrase='mounika')
key = gpg.gen_key(input_data)
with open(local.txt,'rb')as f:
    status=gpg.encrypt_file(f)
```

And the following is the error message being generated.

```
C:\Python27\python.exe C:/SAAS/encrypt.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/SAAS/encrypt.py", line 4, in <module>
    gpg = gnupg.GPG(gnupghome='new')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gnupg.py", line 755, in __init__
    raise OSError(msg)
OSError: Unable to run gpg - it may not be available.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I am fairly new to GnuPG and after doing a bit of research I tried replacing gnupghome with homedir. But this is raising another error that homedir is an unexpected keyword.Can soneone pls help me with this issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the `gpg` program and make sure it is in your `PATH`. Or provide the full path to the `gpg` binary in your constructor, like

```
gpg = gnupg.GPG(gnupghome='new', gpgbinary='C:\\path\\to\\GnuPG\\pub\\gpg.exe')
```

Check also the [Deployment Requirements](https://pythonhosted.org/python-gnupg/#deployment-requirements) for the `python-gnupg` package for more info.

Comment: Can u pls tell me what PATH you are talking about and how can I do that. I have gone through deployment requirements and downloaded and installed the gpg executable.

Comment: Thankyou.. It certainly is working to some extent . I have used the following line ..code..  [ gnupghome='C:\SAAS\wew', gpgbinary='C:\SAAS\gnupg-w32cli-1.4.1.exe'] and this is creating a wew folder now. But then nothing shows up in the console.I tried debugging using pdb but when I type n in pdb nothing is happening there either.

Answer (score 0):

As i encountered, the main reason is your local machine or server doesn't have gnupg package, so you need to install it with `apt` or whatever your package manager is. That could solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

in the latest version(2.2.0) of python-gnupg(imported as gnupg),
gnupghome=homedir(where the keyring etc is stored). 
A few other things:
Binaries(in windows, that's the exe file) are defined as 'binary'.
best to specify a fingerprint, perhaps your local.txt should be a string('local.txt'), 
and I think you're using the [saltycrane blog post](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2011/10/python-gnupg-gpg-example/#encrypt-file) which is a little outdated at the moment.
So the below should work(OP code refactored):

```
import os
import gnupg
import pdb
pdb.set_trace()
gpg = gnupg.GPG(homedir='new',
            binary="C:/Progra~2/GNU/GnuPG/pub/gpg2.exe")
input_data = gpg.gen_key_input(
    key_type="RSA",key_length=1024,
    passphrase='mounika')
key = gpg.gen_key(input_data)
with open(local.txt,'rb')as f:
    status=gpg.encrypt(f, key.fingerprint)
print status.ok
print status.status
print status.stderr
```

I reckon your code is just failing silently.